# If not used in a declared transaction but used in a try...catch will rollback do anything at all?

Tags: php, mysql

My questions are regarding the use of `mysqli::rollback`.

If not used in a declared transaction but used in a `try...catch` will `rollback` do anything at all? (`autocommit` on)

If it does work without a transaction being declared is `rollback` necessary for single query statements? See example below...

```
try{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=?";
    $row = run($mysqli, $sql, [$user_id]);
}catch(exception $e){
    $mysqli->rollback();
    error($mysqli);
}
```

If I have a transaction declared with multiple queries and all queries in the transaction fail, will `rollback` affect an older transaction? What is the scope of `rollback`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You need a declared transaction for a rollback to work.  Declaring a transaction is necessary so that the original state of the data can be held somewhere.  Otherwise, there is nothing to roll back to.

You can easily test this yourself, with and without a transaction, by observing that calling rollback without a transaction has no effect.

**Further Reading**
[PDO.Transactions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Comment: Would there ever be a case where `rollback` would affect a transaction prior to an intended one? Ie one outside of the `try/catch`

Comment: Transactions are not just held open; they have a *scope.*  Once the operations under which the transaction are executed complete, the transaction is committed and then discarded.  Transactions operate independently of `try` `catch` blocks; the `catch` is there merely as a convenience to roll back the transaction if something bad happens.

Answer (score 0):

> No. You need a declared transaction for a rollback to work. Declaring a transaction is necessary so that the original state of the data can be held somewhere. Otherwise, there is nothing to roll back to.
>
> You can easily test this yourself, with and without a transaction, by observing that calling rollback without a transaction has no effect.

It may be true that you have to declare the transaction for PDO (I find PDO extremely tedious, so don't use it often), but for your regular, run-of-the-mill mysqli DB queries, **the transaction begins when mysqli autocommit is set to false**, and **nothing will happen** in the database without a successful commit command.  See [mySQL 14.7.2.2 autocommit, Commit, and Rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) where it states:

> If autocommit mode is disabled within a session with SET autocommit = 0, the session always has a transaction open. A COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement ends the current transaction and a new one starts.

The OP never stated using PDO, so thought I'd drop my $0.02 of non-PDO...  To answer the OP questions:

> If not used in a declared transaction but used in a try...catch will rollback do anything at all? (autocommit on)

**No, rollback won't do anything if you don't have a transaction open** -- whether via PDO declared transaction as @robert-harvey pointed out, or by just setting autocommit to false:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
```

**After that, nothing will be committed to the database without a commit() command.** Then the key is just understanding when to commit and when to roll back...  depending on what you're wanting to do, and where you turned autocommit on or off...

> If I have a transaction declared with multiple queries and all queries in the transaction fail, will rollback affect an older transaction? What is the scope of rollback?

**The scope is the current transaction**, which is reset every time you call commit() or rollback(). So if you start an open transaction and then do 19 (error-free) queries without a commit(), and then the 20th query fails and you do a rollback(), **YES, all 20 queries will be rolled back because they were all treated as a single transaction**.  But if you instead called commit after every successful query, then the rollback would affect only the failed query.

With transnational DB operations, I find that usually its an all-or-nothing scenario: for instance, a single new entry to the database that affects multiple dependent tables.  And in such cases, a rollback isn't even necessary (single transaction, and either it commits or not).  That said, it's good practice to rollback if the commit fails, even if only making it obvious (for you or whoever is viewing your code later) that "all these database commands are null and void".  Plus there are scenarios where you might be running a loop of transactions, and need to reject one without rejecting all of them (as the OP eluded to):

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); // all transactions from here
foreach ($dudes as $id=>$data) {
   $mysqli->query("UPDATE favorites SET last_updated=NOW(), favorite_nba_player='".$data["fav_nba"]."', favorite_food='".$data["fav_food"]."' WHERE dude_id='$id'");
   if ((!$mysqli->affected_rows) or ($mysqli->error) or ($data["fav_nba"] != "Kobe Bryant") or ($data["fav_food"] != "beer")) { // doesn't cut the mustard
      $mysqli->rollback(); // end transaction without commit, and start a new transaction
      echo "Error: information for Dude $id is too weak for this DB.<br>";
      continue; // jump to next iteration of loop (next dude)
   }
   // do another database query...
   // maybe another dozen queries, able to bail out on this loop iteration with a rollback whenever necessary...
   // ....
   // made it to the end of our table updates & inserts, lets make sure it all commits
   if ($mysqli->commmit()) { // new transaction is started regardless. We know all saved to db
      echo "Dude $id is a legit dude; update successful!<br>";
      $saved_dudes++;
   }
   else {
      $mysqli->rollback(); // commit didn't work.  Ensure new transaction is started, and make it clear for anyone viewing/editing the code later
      echo "Dude $id seemed legit, but DB commit failed... ugh!<br>";
   }
$total_dudes++;
}
$mysqli->autocommit(TRUE); // turn autocommit back on - transactions no more
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO dude_update_log SET total_dudes='$total_dudes', saved_dudes='$saved_dudes'"); // executes immediately as usual
```

Comment: Note there is also the context of nested transaction (sometimes called savepoint), where you can partially rollback just the inner transaction without rolling back the outer transaction.